# My water from my dispenser comes out slow even after replacing major parts

Tags: water, refrigerator

Water comes out slow at dispenser even after I replaced the water filter, Filter head assembly and relay. I have ran over a gallon of water to ensure there are no air pockets. I have no kinked or frozen lines. I checked the water reservoir and its not frozen. At my wits end. Please help!!

Comment: We're going to need more information about your system, maybe a few pictures so we can see what you see.

Comment: Water filters restrict flow, so it would be normal and correct for water to dispense slowly (compared with non-filtered/unrestricted flow). Contact time is how many filters actually do what they are supposed to do.

Comment: Hello, I figured it out. It was the saddle valve. I simply decided to go back to the beginning. I turned off the water main to the house. I disconnected the water line from fridge to check if there was low water pressure coming from the saddle valve hose. Sure enough, I received low water pressure. The problem was the saddle valve all along. A simple trip to Lowes for a 13 dollar saddle valve kit fixed the problem. I have bigtime water pressure as if the fridge was new again. I just needed the V8 moment to get this simple fix figured out. Thanks to the community!!

Comment: I was going to bring the saddle valve up but you beat me to it if they don’t plug up they start leaking and the small orifice that you punch through the pipe restricts water to start with. 

You should turn that comment into an answer and accept it, it will help others find an answer with a similar problem (this has been asked in the past here). I will up vote, thanks for returning and letting folks know.

Comment: Hello Ed, Thanks for your advice. Much appreciated. I will try and turn the comment into an answer as you said. Great Idea!! Thanks so much and have a blessed 4th of July. Great Community on here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most problems concerning this slow water issue seems to be the most simplest fix in the world. Getting back to the basics is what help me fix my own problem, even after dumping 100 dollars into my fridge to fix a slow water issue at the dispenser.  It was the saddle valve. I simply decided to go back to the beginning. I turned off the water main to the house. I disconnected the water line from fridge where it comes out of the floor from the saddle valve. Had my wife turn on the water again to see if there was low water pressure coming from the saddle valve hose. Sure enough, I received low water pressure. I turned off the main water valve again and made a trip to Lowes for a 13 dollar saddle valve kit. Just simply replace the old saddle valve connected to your water line or under your sink. This is the cheapest, easiest issue to look at and fix before you call a repair technician or dump 100s in your fridge. I have bigtime water pressure as if the fridge was new again. I just needed the V8 moment to get this simple fix figured out. My fridge is a GE Profile, Stainless Steel, side by side which is about 20 years old. Great refrigerator. No issues at all other than I replaced the relay years ago.
Thanks to everyone. Hope this answer helps others!!

Comment: Better yet, get a tee and a real valve and stop using saddle valves at all. Failure-prone and leak prone, they are best avoided, not replaced with another of the same.

Comment: Awesome answer. Great Idea!